# JavaScript Validation Form / Not Working

Tags: javascript

Absolute newbie here - I'm super passionate about coding and just started with Javascript last week...I cannot seem to get this validation to work! Thanks in advance for all your good advice

-S

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            //Registration Form Validation
                function validate(){

             var firstName=document.getElementById("name").value;
             var maleUser = document.getElementById("maleButton").checked;


             if(firstName=="" || firstName==" "){
                 alert("Please enter your first name: ");

                  return false;
            }

else  if(maleUser==false){
                alert("Please select your gender: ");

            }else{

                return true; window.location.href="Search/index.htm";

          </script>

    <!-- Reg Form needing validation -->
           <h1>Registration Form</h1>
              <p>
              <div class=form_settings>
              <form name="RegForm" onsubmit="return(validate());" >
        First name: <input type="text" name="first_name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your First name" size="35"/>
        <br>
        Gender:
        <input type="radio" name="male" id="maleButton" value="male"> Male
        <br>
         </p>
                  </form>
```

Comment: where is the closing bracket of else block?plz format the code

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the browser console or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct your HTML code:

```
<h1>Registration Form</h1>  
<div class="form_settings">
  <form name="RegForm" action="search/index.htm">
    First name: 
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your First name" size="35"/>
    <br>
    Gender:
    <input type="radio" name="male" id="maleButton" value="male"> Male
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return(validate());">
  </form>
</div>
```

Add this updated JavaScript code:

```
function trim(str) {

   return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}

function validate(){

  var firstName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var maleUser = document.getElementById("maleButton").checked;

  if (trim(firstName) === ''){

    alert("Please enter your first name: ");

    return false;
  }
  else if(maleUser == false){

    alert("Please select your gender: ");

    return false;
  }
  else{

    //window.location.href="Search/index.htm";
    return true; 
  }
}
```

You can see a complete result here: https://jsfiddle.net/logual/ba5f7tkw/

Don't use `window.location.href` to submit form. Add an `action` attribute with url and a submit button to your form.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and got

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

on line 20

you're missing a } after your else

```
else{

            return true; window.location.href="Search/index.htm";
```

Protip: Run in chrome and type CTRL-SHIFT-J